# Could not find the source model '"for the attribute" school " .. Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, error, eav

I see an error in my template when a client tries to register.
You can not register and get an error:
There has been an error processing your request ....

Thanks

```
a:5:{i:0;s:65:"No se ha encontrado el modelo fuente "" para el atributo "school"";i:1;s:3553:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'No se ha encont...')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seams like you have a custom attribute for the customer called `school` that has a custom source model.
Either the source model is empty or the model does not exist.
If you don't need that attribute just remove it from the `eav_table`.
Search for the attribute with the `attribute_code = 'school'`

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the source of the attribute is misconfigured, or the `entity_type` of that attribute is not set.

Search in your database, in the table `eav_attribute` your attribute by `attribute_code` and take a look if the `entity_type` is correct (for example, `catalog_product`, in case of product attributes).

```
SELECT entity_type_id, backend_model, source_model FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'school';
```

If that is correct, it might me a misconfiguration of the Source, check the `source_model` is correct.